# CSS to vertically align a button in purecss

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css

i have a button inside a div which is currently at the top of the div. I want to center it vertically inside iths parent div.

```
.button-login {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #01BDE0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color:#01BDE0;
    width: 100%;
    height:46px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1vw;
    display: block;
}
```

This is css for button.

```
<div class=" pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-24"><button class="button-login">LOG IN</button></div>
```

This is the html part.

I tried vertical align its not working.

Comment: It works here: https://plnkr.co/edit/ukqpHF2pX33sepNqrOfd?p=preview
Maybe in the "pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-24" classes you run something over.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
    <style>
      .pure-u-1 { width:100%;}

      .center {height: 500px; background-color: #222;}

     .vertical-align  {position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); } 
    </style>



    <div class=" pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-24">
  <div class="center" align="center">
    <div class="vertical-align">
    <button class="button-login">LOG IN</button>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.video-contant {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(7, 7, 7, 0.52);
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
  
}
.hctr {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-contant">
    <div class="hctr">
     <button>onewebbell.com<button>
  </div>
</div>
```